# Nagelkerke's Pseudo-R² is negative? How to fix this?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, pseudo-r-squared

I am working on my Master's Thesis and I was fitting various glms on my data; and since I can't calculate adjusted R² values for my models, I opted for Nagelkerke's pseudo R². I used the rcompanion package and the nagelkerke() function to calculate these values for my various models, that I had stored inside a list. I used a loop to calculate the Nagelkerke Pseudo R² for every model inside the list. I didn't notice anything weird there, no errors, no warnings, the values looked fine, so I trusted the results and proceeded.

Now I have a slightly different dataset (a different explanatory variable), I used the same loop and the Nagelkerke Pseudo-R² are ridiculously high, up to 1.8. I've read that this value should be between 0 and 1. So, I picked one of these models (the one that had a Pseudo R² of 1.8) and "hand-recalculated" the nagelkerke R² to see what went wrong. I fit the glm and saved it as a single object, not in a list of glms. When I put it into nagelkerke(), the value it gave me -0.0960369. Its better, but again out of the range(for comparison purposes, I used glm error distribution: gaussian, link function: identity, so I could compare that model and the Pseudo R² to the lm() and the adjusted R², which was -0.003449).

So I thought, well, maybe this package rcompanion also adjusts the Pseudo R² somehow? Hence, I tried to calculate the Nagelkerke Pseudo R² by hand:

```
testdata <-na.omit(testdata)

testmodel_lm <- lm(CSRatio21 ~ FML, data = testdata) #for comparison
testmodel <- glm(CSRatio21 ~ FML, data = testdata, family = gaussian(link="identity"))
summary(testmodel)
nullmodel <- glm(CSRatio21 ~ 1, data = testdata, family = gaussian(link="identity"))

# Number of data points
n <- nrow(testdata)

# residuals testmodel
residuals <- testdata$CSRatio21 - (0.0031229 * testdata$FML + 1.336591) #numbers are intercept and slope estimates from testmodel

# sum of squared residuals
sum_squared_residuals <- sum(residuals^2)

# residual standard deviation (sigma)
sigma <- sqrt(sum_squared_residuals / (n - 2))

# likelihood testmodel
likelihood_linear <- prod(1 / (sigma * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-residuals^2 / (2 * sigma^2)))

loglikmodel <- logLik(testmodel) #second variant

# likelihood null model
null_residuals <- testdata$CSRatio21 - 1.432629
null_sum_squared_residuals <- sum(null_residuals^2)
null_sigma <- sqrt(null_sum_squared_residuals / (n - 1))
likelihood_null <- prod(1/(null_sigma * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-null_residuals^2/(2*null_sigma^2)))

logliknull <- logLik(nullmodel) # second variant
                        
likelihood_ratio <- likelihood_null/likelihood_linear

# Nagelkerke's Pseudo-R²
pseudo_r2 <- ((1-(likelihood_ratio^(2/n)))/(1-(likelihood_null^(2/n))))
 
pseudo_r2_loglik <- (1 - exp(-2/n * (loglikmodel - logliknull)))/((1 - exp(2/n * logliknull))) #second variant

nagelkerke(testmodel)
```

Now, my results are:

- n: 118
- likelihood_linear: 28.89061
- likelihood_null: 19.76952
- logLik(testmodel): 3.372088 (df=3) [why 3 df here though?]
- logLik(nullmodel): 3.068793 (df=2) [and why here 2 and not 1?]

The Pseudo-R²:

- nagelkerke() in loop: 1.823810
- nagelkerke() singular: -0.0960369
- handcalculated with "normal" likelihood (pseudo_r2): -0.123545
- handcalculated with log Likelihood (pseudo_r2_loglik): -0.09603694
- For comparison: the adjusted R² of the lm was -0.003449

So... Still negative...Why? Can I trust these negative values? I thought that Nagelkerke's Pseudo-R² should range between 0 and 1? Looks like I have to re-calculate all of these values, also the ones which I talked about in the beginning?  Which approach should I use now?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Dataset:

```r
testdata <- data.frame(
  FML = c(22.29128, 22.39992, 22.50847, 22.83361, 23.37387, 23.69708, 24.01961, 24.12697, 24.44863, 24.98331, 25.09005, 25.30332, 25.51633, 26.25991, 26.3659, 26.57769, 26.78926, 27.10618, 27.52798, 27.94895, 28.8, 28.8932, 28.8932, 29.98, 30.3, 30.33, 30.4, 30.42, 30.5, 30.73, 30.9, 31.31, 31.31, 31.33, 31.39, 31.8, 32, 32.13, 32.14, 32.25, 32.47, 32.5, 32.53, 32.6, 32.62, 32.69, 32.8, 32.85, 33, 33.1, 33.22, 33.84, 33.92, 33.99, 34, 34.06, 34.4, 34.45, 34.6, 34.6, 34.61, 34.68, 34.82, 34.84, 34.87, 34.87, 34.92, 35.03, 35.07, 35.12, 35.19, 35.21, 35.35, 35.44, 35.46, 35.79, 35.89, 36.18, 36.2, 36.29, 36.33, 36.35, 36.4, 36.46, 36.5, 36.6, 36.92, 36.92, 36.96, 36.97, 37.02, 37.11, 37.21, 37.24, 37.3, 37.4, 37.44, 37.49, 37.5, 37.62, 37.78, 37.78, 37.87, 38.02, 38.05, 38.17, 38.19, 38.44, 38.6, 38.64, 38.77, 39.53, 41, 42.18, 42.5, 43.3, 43.89, 60.6),
  CSRatio21 = c(1.4774311, 1.22585, 1.3784473, 1.6238005, 1.3249576, 1.7084772, 1.5943105, 1.9541404, 1.1171914, 1.3236172, 1.2929554, 1.0386303, 1.561736, 1.3239787, 1.1792404, 1.9197001, 1.4155338, 1.543906, 1.6820963, 1.6484193, 1.4603812, 1.5447676, 1.3982134, 1.3560707, 1.684361, 1.2844309, 1.5050369, 1.246091, 1.5280047, 1.4810207, 1.8660375, 1.1933631, 1.2836483, 1.0328543, 1.7887168, 1.4201204, 1.0225164, 1.3032925, 1.2286226, 0.9198779, 1.6436054, 1.5337189, 1.537951, 1.1403919, 1.6007158, 1.337508, 1.5251319, 0.9975092, 1.7674451, 1.7825995, 1.4685762, 1.7518935, 1.5658627, 1.2009758, 1.1491171, 1.6162482, 1.8831728, 1.6755523, 1.7600169, 1.448914, 1.5329522, 1.1955977, 1.5366577, 1.4699221, 1.3493276, 1.3176134, 1.4754639, 1.4144239, 1.5749245, 1.4713806, 1.4195688, 1.371345, 1.3518266, 1.0300401, 1.4767193, 1.4706224, 1.2066236, 1.1956105, 1.3105297, 1.1632983, 1.2868495, 1.3720136, 1.1776412, 1.3619443, 1.3287843, 1.7111001, 1.2242829, 1.5002895, 1.9023916, 1.398345, 1.1438687, 1.5444296, 1.5875994, 1.5138578, 1.8444355, 1.4297542, 1.5532971, 1.0265456, 1.6225182, 1.9630474, 1.2549328, 1.2016863, 1.1794137, 1.0864437, 1.2412811, 1.3124565, 1.6559418, 1.6567076, 1.4177803, 1.9896252, 1.112104, 1.5502013, 1.384694, 1.662408, 1.326554, 1.5228765, 1.5544942, 1.8852055)
)
```

Also, some additional info:

- nullmodel and linear model have the same length and the same family
  (see code)
- NAs are ommited (see code)
- my code here is not a loop anymore, my problem are the now negative
  values (without the loop, and one singular model + nullmodel). I did this "individual approach" to see if the Nagelkerke R² > 1 problem that I had in the loop persists - it did not, but now I have negative values... x)
- I calculate a lm as a glm to have an adjusted R² value that I can
  compare the Nagelkerke values to. I will have glms with the families
  Gaussian, Gamma, Inverse Gaussian and the link functions identity,
  inverse, log, (1/mu²). The code I provided is basically at a method
  testing stage.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it seems like you are doing "regular" regression, so, why can't you use adjusted R squared?

Comment: I can't remember what error checking these functions do, but do you have any missing values for FML? That would cause weird results as the data sets wouldn't be the same size for your two models.

Comment: @AaronleftStackOverflow , good point.  That's probably (at least partially) the explanation.  If you add `FML[1:6] = NA` as the fourth line in my code below, I can get some negative values, or values over 2 for different runs. ... In my defense, the documentation for `rcompanion::nagelkerke()` does have a note about `NA` values, and also has a `restrictNobs=TRUE` option, that may alleviate the issue.

Comment: @SalMangiafico While we are making wild guesses, the code snippet starts with `testdata = na.omit(testdata)` so it can't be NA values?

Comment: It's hard to see how this issue can be resolved without the data. @Pauline Can you share the dataset or provide a simulated dataset which exhibits the same problem?

Comment: @dipetkov, Ah! Thanks.  I missed that !

Comment: 1. The models where the Nagelkerke R² went crazy, were basically all: Gaussian, inverse gaussian, and Gamma error distribution. However, they apparently go crazy if it's in the loop. I know that, but my question is: why is it now negative, why do the different approaches (likelihood vs log likelihood) give different results, is any of this reliable, and: which approach should I choose? 2. missing values are gone, see first line of my code that I shared here.

Comment: I don't think the Nagelkerke statistic will be less than 0 or more than 1 when used correctly, but this can happen in unusual circumstances, where the models aren't properly nested. In my experience, often when `NA`s result in one model having a different number of observations than the other.

Comment: I think the Nagelkerke should be fine with Gamma or Gaussian, and I imagine with inverse Gaussian.  There may be other models where it can be calculated from a reported likelihood, but may not behave well.

Comment: All this said, I think the first thing to do is, as @dipetkov, provide a reproducible example that shows this behavior. ...  I suspect your problem has to do with the loop, and maybe with ending up with models that aren't properly nested, probably due to `NA`s sneaking in, or maybe not having the families match on the model and null model, or something similar.

Comment: Comment from O.P.: “*In this particular case I am computing a lm as glm to have the adjusted R² to compare. For my data, I want to also fit glms with other error distributions (inverse gaussian, gamma) and other link functions (inverse, log). So, this is basically at a method testing stage.*”

Comment: Comment from O.P.: “*The models where the Nagelkerke R² went crazy, were basically all: Gaussian, inverse gaussian, and Gamma error distribution. However, they apparently go crazy if it's in the loop. I know that, but my question is: why is it now negative, why do the different approaches (likelihood vs log likelihood) give different results, is any of this reliable, and: which approach should I choose?*”

Comment: Comment from O.P.: “*Missing values are gone, see first line of my code that I shared here.*”

Comment: Hey! So, as I stated earlier: My problem is not that the values go over 1 in the loop. As you can see in my code snippet, this is not a loop anymore. The problem that I have now is, that it is negative and that the different approaches result in different results (except in one case), and I don't know which approach is the one to trust, if I can trust one of these at all because Nagelkerke should be between 0 and 1, not negative. I will provide a dataset shortly. Thanks for your support!

Comment: I've edited the question to replace the markdown data table with R code to declare the testdata frame. This way the whole question fits in a single screen.  I used [datapasta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/index.html) to do this; it's very handy to make copy-pastable data structures in R.

Comment: Yes, so, as @dipetkov explains, the negative Nagelkerke pseudo r-square makes sense in this case.  Just as point of interest, it's similar to the McFadden value.  In contrast, the Cox and Snell and Efron pseudo r-squared are slightly positive (c. 0.005). I wouldn't worry about the negative values;  they make sense in these cases.  Use whichever pseudo r-squared measure you think is most useful or appropriate for your purpose. FYI: You can get Efron's pseudo r-squared with `library(rcompanion); efronRSquared(testmodel)` or with `library(DescTools); PseudoR2(testmodel, which="Efron")`

Comment: @SalMangiafico, thank you so much! But, how should I discuss the negative values in the thesis, as the only literature I have found so far tells me that nagelkerke has a mathematical range of (0,1)? Unfortunately, my supervisors couldn't even help me with glms in the first place, so I am kind of on my own here. I really appreciate your help and advice! Thank you!

Comment: Basically, the pseudo r-square is negative because the fitted model predicts the values worse than the null model.  But you can describe this in terms of likelihood values if you want a more technical explanation.

Answer (score 4):

There is a single highly influential data point in your dataset (an outlier?) As a result the full model `y ~ x` fits the data worse than the null (intercept-only) model `y ~ 1`. That's what the negative R-squared is telling you.

This is straightforward to see in a scatter plot of the outcome (y = CSRatio21) against the predictor (x = FML) with the two regression lines superimposed. Graphing the data should probably be the first analysis step: `plot(y ~ x)` is more informative than any single number such as Nagelkerke pseudo R-squared.

[image]

About the by-hand calculations not matching the rcompanion calculations. You've hard-coded the coefficient estimates and the intercept coefficient for the null model is copied incorrectly. Your calculations are also all on the original scale, not on the log scale, so there may be loss of numerical precision as well.

```r
# hard-coded residual calculations
# residuals <- testdata$CSRatio21 - (0.0031229 * testdata$FML + 1.336591)
# null_residuals <- testdata$CSRatio21 - 1.432629

# coefficient estimates from the full and null models
coef(lm(CSRatio21 ~ FML, data = testdata))
#> (Intercept)         FML 
#>  1.33659065  0.00312292
coef(lm(CSRatio21 ~ 1, data = testdata))
#> (Intercept) 
#>    1.441449
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed a datapoint that is likely a real outlier / mismeasurement, I definetly will throw it out. However, I don't quite understand how this mathematically can lead to the negative value? Anyway this is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Start with the formula for Nagelkerke's R squared and compute it twice: once assuming that the null model is better (has higher log-likelihood) and then assuming that the full model is better (has higher log-likelihood).

Comment: Spoke too soon. I think with your dataset it's the case that logLik(full_model) > logLik(null_model) but the difference is small and the arithmetic works such that the numerator is positive and denominator is negative. (Plug the values in to the formula to try it out.)

Comment: So in addition we learn not to use (pseudo) R-squared to compare to bad and/or ineffective models.

Answer (score 3):

This may be more of a comment.  At least for the example below, the Nagelkerke pseudo r-squared from the `rcompanion` package, from the `DescTools` package, and from your `# variant 2` calculation all return the same result.

Note that in your question, your `handcalculated with log Likelihood (pseudo_r2_loglik)` and `nagelkerke() singular` return the same result.

Likely one issue is with the loop, perhaps with what you are using as the null model somewhere.

It may also be that the with the family of glm in your orginial model, that the Nagelkerke calculation behaves strangely.  What was the original family ?

```
N = 30
CSRatio21 = rnorm(N, 0, 1)
FML = c(rep("A", N/2), rep("B", N/2))
testdata = data.frame(CSRatio21=CSRatio21, FML=FML)

testmodel <- glm(CSRatio21 ~ FML, data = testdata, family = gaussian(link="identity"))
nullmodel <- glm(CSRatio21 ~ 1, data = testdata, family = gaussian(link="identity"))

library(rcompanion)
nagelkerke(testmodel)$Pseudo.R.squared.for.model.vs.null[3]

library(DescTools)
PseudoR2(testmodel, which="Nagelkerke")

n=length(testdata[,1])
loglikmodel <- logLik(testmodel)
logliknull <- logLik(nullmodel)
pseudo_r2_loglik <- (1 - exp(-2/n * (loglikmodel - logliknull)))/((1 - exp(2/n * logliknull)))
as.numeric(pseudo_r2_loglik)
```